# Making a ball bounce around screen forever?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from Tkinter import *
window = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(window, width=500, height=500, background="green")
canvas.pack()

x0 = 225
y0 = 225
x1 = 275
y1 = 275
speed_x = 2
speed_y = 3

ball = canvas.create_oval(x0,y0,x1,y1,fill="blue", tag='ball')
while True:
    canvas.move('ball', speed_x, speed_y)
    canvas.after(30)
    canvas.update()

    if x1 >= 500:
        speed_x = -2
    if x0 <= 500:
        speed_y = -3
    if y1 >= 0:
        speed_y = 2
    if y0 <= 0:
        speed_x = 3

    x0 += speed_x
    x1 += speed_x
    y0 += speed_y
    y1 += speed_y

mainloop()
```

My goal is to make the ball bounce around the screen forever. Right now the ball bounces off the right wall, but then goes and disappears into the bottom wall.

Comment: You can post code in your question, you know? No one wants to follow a link to find your problem. Also, you are asking for us to do it for you? Describe the problem you have and how you have tried to solve it.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I'm new to this website so I wasn't sure, I usually use reddit when asking questions and you can't post your code on there. I will fix this.

Comment: Also, I was just looking to get some hints because I'm completely lost. I've been trying to come up with ways to do this but I got nothing. I would appreciate any hints and maybe suggestions of functions I could use.

Comment: You'll need to mod the x and y coordinates with the max windows sizes in order to "wrap" around the window. Bouncing requires an if statement for each edge of the window that'll reverse the direction of the ball

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is a very simple logic problem

This is what you have written:

```
if x1 >= WIDTH: speed_x = -velocity
if x0 <= WIDTH: speed_y = -(velocity+1)
if y1 > 0:      speed_y = velocity
if y0 < 0:      speed_x = (velocity+1)
```

What we want to say is that if we are outside any boundary condition, invert our velocity along the appropriate component.

Maybe you're immediately suspicious that you never check the y-position against the height, or maybe you're suspicious that you're adjusting the y-speed based on the x-position. Either way, be suspicious

Here is what you've written, in order

1. If our right point is too right, start moving left. Check.
2. If our left point is... inside the right border (?), move left... but more quickly. This doesn't make sense.
3. If our top point below the top line, move down. Okay... but not too useful. That doesn't correct any mistakes
4. If our bottom point is above the top line, move down. Close, but we probably want to bounce when our top point is above the top line, not the bottom point. Small difference, but as long as we're fixing things.

Compare to this logic:

```
if x1 >= WIDTH:     speed_x = -velocity
if x0 <= 0:         speed_x = velocity
if y1 >= HEIGHT:    speed_y = -velocity
if y0 <= 0:         speed_y = velocity
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand how coordinates work much better now. There is still one problem I can't seem to figure out though. I changed the part of the code you were talking to basically to exactly what you wrote.

It looks like it should work, y0 is the top part of the oval, and as it hits 0, it should go the opposite way. What did I do wrong this time?

Comment: @Astrosphere what is happening? I just ran it with the conditionals I suggested in my answer (which do look like what you've written in your comment) and it bounces just fine

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out how to put codes into comments, sorry about that.

For some reason the ball doesn't bounce off the top wall when I test it. I have no idea why.

Comment: I edited the code in the question to what I have now, do you see a mistake? It looks correct to me.

Comment: Please undo that edit; if you edit your original question like that then my answer looks like nonsense and future readers will not be able to be helped (which is the point of the site, after helping you of course). Running your code exactly as written now, there is no bouncing problem on my end.

Comment: Oh, yes. I didn't think about that. I will undo it now, thank you.

Comment: No problem, if my answer helped you, feel free to upvote and accept